# Is it a good idea to communicate between services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, communication

I was thinking of using one service to store variables and call another service which stores the functions that call the web API that would be called by service1 - would this be a bad idea?

For example, I have a controller that only gets the values from Service1:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.event')
    .controller('Controller1', Controller1);
Controller1.$inject = ['service1', '$stateParams'];

/**
 * Controller 1
 * @constructor
 */
function Controller1(service1, $stateParams) {
    // Declare self and variables
    var vm = this;
    vm.number = 0;

    init();

    /**
     * Initializes the controller
     */
    function init() {
        service1.refreshCount($stateParams.id);
        vm.number = service1.getCount();
    }
}
})();
```

Below is Service 1, which only stores variables and a reference to a function which is in Service2:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.event')
        .factory('service1', service1);

    service1.$inject = ['service2'];

    /**
     * The event index service
     * @constructor
     */
    function service1(service2) {
        // Declare
        var count = 0;

        // Create the service object with functions in it
        var service = {
            getCount: getCount,
            setCount: setCount,
            refreshCount: refreshCount
        };

        return service;

        ///////////////
        // Functions //
        ///////////////

        /**
         * Refreshes the count value
         */
        function refreshCount(id) {
            service2.getCounts(id).then(
                function (response) {
                    setCount(response.data.Count);
            });
        }

        /**
         * Returns the count value
         */
        function getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        /**
         * Updates the count
         * @param {int} newCount - The new count value
         */
        function setCount(newCount) {
            count = newCount;
        }
    }
})();
```

And below would be a part of Service2, where the function is called from Service1:

```
// Gets a count from the DB
getCounts: function(id) {
    $http({ url: APP_URLS.api + 'WebApiMethodName/' + id, method: 'GET' }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.Count;
    });
},
etc : function() {},
etc : function() {}
```

Is this a good idea, or is there something bad about communicating between services in this way?